# Powershell: Grab characters from next line until a specific number of characters

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have a text file that after 80 characters per line pushes the remaining characters to the next line. So I'd like to see how I can create a logic that allows me to capture the next 48 characters from the following line only when there is 80 characters in the first line.

Example (Note: Stack only allows 76 characters per line, but same idea)

Sample File:

```
This is a test where I would like this entire line and everything that will 
be g
oing to this line up until character 48.                 08/31/2017
```

So basically my variable would hold the following:

```
This is a test where I would like this entire line and everything that will 
be going to this line up until character 48.
```

This is my current code that started the logic:

```
$lineArray = Get-Content "c:\sample.txt"
ForEach ($line in $lineArray )
 If ($line.length -eq 80) {Write-Host $line.length " - Max characters 
 Reached"}
 else {Write-Host $line.length " - Within Limits"} 
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: During your loop you should be able to count each character and push it into whatever variable is needed. Your code right now is only going to tell you if a line has 80 characters in it.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone curious... I was able to accomplish it by using the following code:

```
$lineArray = Get-Content "C:\sample.txt"
$lineNumber = 0

ForEach ($line in $lineArray )
 {#Write-Host $line.length

  If ($line.length -eq 80) 
   {#Write-Host $line.length " - Max characters Reached" 
    $nextLine = $lineArray[$lineNumber +1]
    $retrieve48 = $nextLine.substring(0,48)  
    $newLine = $line + $retrieve48
    Write-Host = $newLine
   }
  else {Write-Host $line.length " - Within Limits"} 
  $lineNumber++
  }
```

Comment: You may want to look into using a for loop instead of a foreach loop for this. With a for loop you are increasing a variable number each time so you know exactly where the loop is. You don't have to have an outside variable like `$lineNumber` counting up for you.

Comment: One other thing is you may have an issue with duplicated text if you have two lines that are both 80 characters following each other.

Comment: Hi Jason, good idea about the For Loop vs. ForEach. Regarding your second comment, I know for a fact I won't have 2 consecutive lines with 80 characters each...but yeah, that would have been a problem! Thx